# Rest api to get issues count based on rules for a project in Sonar

Tags: sonarqube, devops, sonarqube6.3

I want to know how to get the issues count in sonar based on the rules for a given project through REST API.

Answer (score 1):

In the footer of each page of the SonarQube UI you'll find a link to the API docs for your version. Take a look at [issues/search](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/issues/search), which you can qualify by `componentKeys` (project id). In the response JSON (you can see an example in the on-board docs) look at `paging.total`

Answer (score 0):

The REST API endpoint that can answer such queries is [api/issues/search](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/issues).

For example given the `$KEY` of a project, you can find the number of issues using `curl` and the `jq` tool like this:

```
curl "yourserver/api/issues/search?componentKeys=$KEY&ps=1" | jq .total
```

That is:

- Set the project key in the `componentKeys` parameter
- Use the *minimum* page size with `ps=1` to minimize the output

This will return one issue, thanks to `ps=1`,
but in the JSON response you should see the `total` field, which contains the total number of issues.

The `jq` tool will give you a clean output of a single number, if you don't have it, you can simple get the `head` of the response instead, the value should be easily visible near the top, for example:

```
$ curl "yourserver/api/issues/search?componentKeys=$KEY&ps=1" | jq .total
{
  "total": 12,
  "p": 1,
  "ps": 1,
  "paging": {
    "pageIndex": 1,
    "pageSize": 1,
    "total": 12
  },
  "issues": [
```

(In this example there are 12 issues in the project.)